# show minimum advertising price instead of price if avaliable in magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Once again thanks for viewing this post i would like to mention that i need a requirement of map price in magento what actually i need . I am having some product which have MAP price and also price , so on listing of product if map price is available then system will show map price because vender cant sell below the map price,

Example:
MAP: $3
Price : $2
Then System Will Show MAP Price Of Product in this case.

Do i need to override core functionality for catalog price product rule or is there anyway to show that map price on .phtml file. If  i do condition on price in phtml file will it get affected on all like in cart and detail pages. or do i need to make changes on everywhere.
If i want to override the rule then in which file i need to change

And do MAP Configuration but it show price on everywhere on cart to am i doing wrong with MAP configuration.

Please help me Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a condition inside your template (phtml) file would cause issues for you. This price would be shown to the visitor, but the actual price field would be used in calculations / cart etc so there could be a mismatch.

The simplest way to do what you want would probably be to override the Product model and/or Product Price Model.

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
```

there's a load of guides on how to override models:

```
http://magento4u.wordpress.com/tag/override-catalog-product-model/
```

For simplicity you could just copy the class into the local namespace which would override the class without having to create a module/xml etc.

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{
    /**
     * Default action to get price of product
     *
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getPrice($product)
    {
        if($product->getMsrp() > $product->getData('price')) {
            return $product->getMsrp();
        }

        return $product->getData('price');
    }
}
```

Something like that might do the trick, although it;s not tested in anyway shape or form but it might help get you started..

or override the getPrice method inside the product class

**Mage_Catalog_Model_Product**

```
/**
 * Get product price throught type instance
 *
 * @return unknown
 */
public function getPrice()
{
    if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData('price')) {
        $price = $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this);
    } else {
        $price = $this->getData('price');
    }

    if($this->getMsrp() > $price) {
        return $this->getMsrp();
    }

    return $price;
}
```

You can see sometimes it may not be using the price model, so it may be better to override the getPrice method in the product class.. try it out.

Comment: Thanks For you help Andrew at least i got an idea i made changes on core files just to test but not effected on this page

https://u2mobility.com/bathroom-safety.html
price still not Changed

Comment: have you actually set the msrp price value higher than the price too? :)

Comment: yes i did i am getting price but when special price calculate it take minimum price on cart page so i am not getting with map price what to do next andrew and really your guide is helping me

Comment: Are you using grouped or confiugrable products by any chance? they have their own Price models, you can find them in the same place :)

Comment: Andrew yes you are right if i made changes on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product it affecting but if i dont have this msrp i am having someanother field like (map) i have created this attribute but when i tried to get this using this $this->getData('map'); or $this->getMap(); i am not getting anything so help me to get this attribute value